# Display tags value from database inside a Multiple Select Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have this Form that sends data to my Database like this 1, 2, 3, 4 but in the selection it is in boxes [1][2][3][4]

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <select name="Name[]" id="ID" multiple="multiple" class="Class" value="if(isset($name){echo $name;}else{echo '';}">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>                
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

But when i callback the values from database to the form again, I get it like this [1, 2, 3, 4] in single box, **How can i callback the values in single boxes for each value And make it already SELECTED in the form?** (I use multiple select semantic ui framework)

Comment: what do you mean by you have values in boxes?? are you using any kind of plugin as you said about some ui framework??

Comment: Your select is an array, so the boxes are an array with data. The data inside the "boxes" are the value that the user has select in the options. You just need to explode the "boxes"

Comment: @RohitS Yea, like the tags in this question, But using a framework to style it.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi How exactly can i explode it into my form?

Comment: $values = implode(",",$_POST['Name']);

Comment: @J.4RK hey, i am still not clear what you mean by using framework for stying but if its some plugin like select2 to you have to split values in multiple array using function explode() and then pass the values to plugin...

Comment: @RafaelShkembi I tried the code but still give me a single selection-box

`<?php  
$tags='V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X'; 
$tagse =  explode(',', $tags);
?>
<select id="tags" class="ui search selection dropdown" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
   
    <option selected>
    <?php foreach ($tagse as $tag) {echo ",$tag";} ?>
    </option>
    
</select>`

Comment: @RohitS Like this [link](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Just figured it out, I need to put the entire <OPTION> inside the foreach.

Comment: @J.4RK thanks for the link..and as from your code you have posted try putting the option tag within your foreach loop like 

<?php $tags='V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X'; $tagse = explode(',', $tags); ?> <select id="tags" class="ui search selection dropdown" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple"> <?php foreach ($tagse as $tag) {echo "<option selected>".$tag." </option> ";} ?></select>